# How to solve compilation target framework 4.5 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I want to deploy my ASP.Net site on IIS on my own server. I already deployed one site, that is currently in **Active**, that active site working on **version 2**

[IIS image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOw01.png)

> You can see **DefaultAppPool** that is my old website, that version is 2.
>   My new website called **Matejer Report**
>
> when I do deploy on IIS of my local machine, it's working fine. But when I try to deploy on my server it's showing the following error

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPxpp.png)

So, Do you I need to install **.Net Framework 4.5?**,

If, yes How to install on windows server 2008 R2?.

I already downloaded the file www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42642. Is it correct link?

After I install it, **Will it affect the old webisite (DefaultAppPool) which is running on version 2.0?**

Comment: I suggest you to create new app Pool for .net 4.5 rather than using `DefualtAppPool`. If you don't have .net 4.5 in your system you have to install it. https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: Your Asp.Net web site seems to work with version 4.5 then install it. To my knowledge it will not affect your old website as the new framework will not override the old one.

Comment: @SankarRaj That was old one. It is working fine now. I think it doesn't matter now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to here [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx)

and go to Download [page for 4.5 web installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) and select your language and click on Red download button.